# Strong induction - prove that $n \le 3^\frac{n}3$ for every integer $n \ge 0$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

This question was asked somewhere else, but I am having trouble with the algebra in the inductive step. And if you don't mind, let me know if anything else seems blatantly wrong as well.

So far I have :

Assume the predicate $P(n)$, where $n \le 3^\frac{n}3$. We will prove this is true for every $n\ge 0$ via strong induction. 
**Basis:**
$P(0)= 0 \le 1$, $P(1)= 1\le 3^\frac13$, $P(2)= 2\le3^\frac23$, $P(3)= 3=3$ holds for first four numbers

**Inductive Step:**
Let $n=k$. Assume that $P(k)$ is true where $k$ is $3 \le i \le k$ and $i$ being some integer less than $k$. We will prove this also holds for the $k+1$ case:
$4 + 5 + ... + k + (k+1) \le 3^\frac{k+1}3$.

Using algebra:
$-(k+1) \le 3^\frac13 * 3^\frac{k}3$
$-3^{-\frac13}*(k+1) \le 3^\frac{k}3$
$-3^{-\frac13}*(k+1) \le k$ (substituting $P(k)$ back in)
stuck here...

Comment: "This question was asked somewhere else" could you maybe provide a link to the original?

Comment: Sorry,  it was ask here, but i was still a little confused. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1025734/use-strong-induction-to-prove-that-n-leq3n-3-for-every-integer-n-geq0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you know it is true up to $k$.  For $k \ge 4$ we have 
$$3^{\frac {k+1}3}=3\cdot 3^{\frac {k-2}3}\ge 3\cdot (k-2)\gt k+1$$

Comment: I still a little unsure of your reasoning for this. So, you split 3^((k+1)/3) up into 3 * 3^((k-2)/3) and set it greater than equal to  3 * (k-2). Why?

Comment: In an induction proof you want to relate the new case to an old one that has been proven.  The first step brings in the same expression for $k-2$ which we assume has already been proven.  The second step makes use of what has been proven.  I think [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19485/dominoes-and-induction-or-how-does-induction-work/19488#19488) is a great discussion

Comment: Ahh, I see. In strong induction, we assume two things. For this example k, but also all its predecessors. I think I understand. Appreciate the link as well, definitely will give it a read.

Comment: Yes, that is the difference between strong induction and normal induction.  In this case we really have three chains going upward, one for numbers $0 \bmod 3$, one for $1 \bmod 3$ and one for $2 \bmod 3$.  We could formulate it as normal induction for each of those.  We could also do normal induction by splitting off a factor $\sqrt[3]3$ instead of a factor $3$.  There are many routes to the solution here.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: I would prove that $$n^3\le 3^n$$ then we have to Show that $$(n+1)^3\le 3^{n+1}$$
Multiplying the first inequality by $3$ we get
$$3^{n+1}\geq 3n^3\geq (n+1)^3$$

Comment: So you think that $3 = 3\times1^3 \ge (1+1)^3 = 8 $?

Comment: All examples for which this inequality not hold can you check, for all other numbers this inequality is true.

Comment: This inequalitiy is true for all $$n\geq n_0$$

Comment: Again: Why do you think that  $3n^3 \ge (n+1)^3?$ This is complete non-sense.

Comment: So we have $$3n^3\geq (n+1)^3$$ if $$n(\sqrt[3]{3}-1)\geq 1$$ this is $$n\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{3}-1}$$

Comment: What you says is nonsense, read about the induction principle

Comment: $$??? $$
Substitute $n=1$ in your inequality $3^{n+1}\geq 3n^3\geq (n+1)^3$ and
get $9 \ge 3 \ge 8$. Do you agree that this is complete non-sense?

Comment: @gammatester $3n^3- (n+1)^3=
2 n^3 - 3 n^2 - 3 n - 1\geq 0$ for $n>2$ isn't it?

Comment: I will say it again, your statement is nonsense at all.

Comment: Every induction prove must NOT start for $n=1$!!!!

Comment: It is **your** statement. Again: substitue $n=1$ in **your** inequality.

Comment: Again. read about the induction principle!

Comment: @gammatester $\mathbf{n > 2}$

Comment: Why don't you try the substitution?

Comment: @Surb: No $n\ge 0$ in the original question. I do not read that $n>2$ in the Doctor's answer.

Comment: @gammatester Well, OP has checked the claim for $n=0,1,2,3$.

Comment: @Surb: Yes, and I do not say the statement is wrong. But the answer, as it stands, is missing this detail. In the comments the Dr. admitted that the inequality is valid for $n\ge n_0.$ This should be added to the answer.

Comment: The answer of Dr. SG is a Hint. It is clearly written there. A hint has not to contain all details.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear for $n = 1,2,3,4$. (Base cases). Assume it is true for $n$, now notice that
\begin{equation}
 n+1\leq 3^{\frac{n}{3}} + 1
 =
 3^{-\frac{1}{3}}3^{\frac{n+1}{3}} + 1
\end{equation}
But the function $f(x) = 3^{-\frac{1}{3}}x + 1 \leq x$ for $x \in [x_0,\infty]$ where $x_0 = \frac{1}{1-3^{-\frac{1}{3}}} \simeq 3.2612$. So we have proved it for $n \geq 4$.

Comment: how do you find $x_0$?

Comment: Find the intersection $3^{-\frac{1}{3}}x + 1 = x$ and solve for $x$. @Surb

Comment: How did you get 3^(n/3) + 1 in the first part? Shouldn't it just be 3^((n+1)/3)?

Comment: By induction hypothesis, you have that $n \leq 3^{n/3}$. So just add $1$ on both sides.